# I am not succeeding in checking my input file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

What check did I miss that my edit page only works if it has a file selected?
I tried to make some conditionals in the **onSubmit** function but I haven't found the way yet.

I know it has to do with the image array because when I click edit without selecting a file I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

```js
<script setup>
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
import {
getStorage,
uploadBytesResumable,
ref as firebaseRef,
getDownloadURL
} from 'firebase/storage'
import { doc, updateDoc, getDoc, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from '../../firebase.config.js'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'

const themeEditListing = ref([])

const formData = ref({
name: '',
})

const route = useRoute()

// get the theme id from the route
const themeId = route.params.id

const auth = getAuth()
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
if (user) {
    // set user on formData
    formData.value.user = user.uid
} else {
    navigateTo('/')
}
})

const fetchEditListing = async () => {
const docRef = doc(db, 'themes', themeId)
// response
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)

if (docSnap.exists) {
    themeEditListing.value = docSnap.data()
    formData.value = themeEditListing.value
}
}

fetchEditListing()

const onSubmit = async () => {
const newImgUrls = await Promise.all(
    Array.from(formData.value.images).map((image) => {
        return storeImage(image)
    })
).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})

const imgUrls = newImgUrls ? formData.value.imgUrls.concat(newImgUrls) : formData.value.imgUrls
const formDataCopy = { ...formData.value, imgUrls, timestamp: serverTimestamp() }
delete formDataCopy.images

// update listing
// get doc reference
const docRef = doc(db, 'themes', themeId)

// update doc
await updateDoc(docRef, formDataCopy)

formData.value = { ...formData.value, imgUrls }

}

const onFileChange = (e) => {
const file = e.target.files
formData.value.images = file
}

// store images in firebase storage
const storeImage = async (image) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    formData.value.imgUrls.push('')
    newImgProgress.value = 1
    const storage = getStorage()
    const fileName = `${auth.currentUser.uid}-${image.name}-${uuidv4()}`
    const storageRef = firebaseRef(storage, 'images/' + fileName)
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image)
    uploadTask.on(
        'state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
            newImgProgress.value = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
            console.log('Upload is ' + newImgProgress.value + '% done')
            switch (snapshot.state) {
                case 'paused':
                    console.log('O Upload está parado')
                    break
                case 'running':
                    console.log('Subindo a Imagem')
                    break
                default:
                    break
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            reject(error)
        },
        () => {
            // Handle successful uploads on complete
            getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
                // pop the last element
                formData.value.imgUrls.pop()
                newImgProgress.value = 0
                resolve(downloadURL)
            })
        }
    )
})
}

</script>

<template>


<div>
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" class="w-full border shadow-md p-4 rounded-md">

        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                @value="formData.name"
                v-model="formData.name"
                placeholder="Nome do Tema"
                class="input w-full border-x-indigo-300"
            />
        </div>
        
        <div>
                <input
                    type="file"
                    id="images"
                    @value="formData.images"
                    @change="onFileChange"
                    accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg, .webp"
                    multiple
                    class="hidden"
                />
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit"">Edit Theme</button>
</form>
</div>

</template>
```

I edited the code as much as possible to make it short to read.

Comment: I can't see any `v-for`s or arrey descructors.. Please provide the whole error stack.

Comment: There is no v for.